# How to use getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method)

Tags: checkout

I'm looking to programmatically add an extra label to my payment options and while studying methods.phtml I see the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method); ?>
```

Now it seems this is exactly what I need, but I have no idea how to use it. It sure looks very similar to:

```
<?php if ($html = $this->getPaymentMethodFormHtml($_method)): ?>
<dd>
    <?php echo $html; ?>
</dd>
```

I know this calls the form.pthml corresponding to the currently parsed payment method. Does getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method) also work with a .pthml file? And if yes, where do I put it and are there examples available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you need to do is call the function `setMethodLabelAfterHtml` on your payment block and pass this function the html that you want to display.

I good example of this is found in the module `Mage_Paypal`.

Here the block `Mage_Paypal_Block_Standard_Form` which extends `Mage_Payment_Block_Form` calls this `setMethodLabelAfterHtml` during the `_construct`

Basically what you would need to do is make a block using type `core/template`, sets the desired template and then passes the result of this block's `toHtml` function into `setMethodLabelAfterHtml`.

```
$mark = Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('core/template');
$mark = new $mark;
$mark->setTemplate('your /custom/template.phtml');
$this->setMethodLabelAfterHtml($mark->toHtml())
return parent::_consturct();
```